# Narrow down Favorites with filters feature request

Tags: feature-request

I don't know if this is a new [feature-request](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) or it's already available.

Every day I mark questions with the `favorite` button and I'm collecting too many to effectively review them. For example, today I marked 2 more Nvidia problems in Ubuntu 16.04 as favorites. What if one day I have a *Matrix Moment* by taking the blue pill and now know everything about Nvidia? OK it's unlikely, but how do I find all my favorites that are tagged [nvidia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/nvidia) and [16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/16.04) by the OP? I would need to do this to share my enlightenment to all the OPs.

I propose a [feature-request](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) to filter favorites using advanced options but specifically by OP tag(s). **AND**, **OR**, **XOR** and **NOT** could be supported for multiple tags but that gets complicated with lots of brackets. Filtering by date and title word(s) could also be provided. I think the >3K club members could come up with even more filtering ideas and I hope they speak up (ok type up).

Bonus [feature-request](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) to create personal categories such as `Education`, `Testing`, `Grub`, `EFI`, `Nautilus`, `bc`, `ls`, `awk`, `grep`, `sed` and `Intel cstate / pstate` and apply them to your favorites. Essentially creating your own tags to group favorites together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of exists using the advanced search function.

To get your favourites search

```
infavorites:mine
```

and to search a specific tag, for example Nvidia

```
[nvidia]
```

Now if you put them together

```
infavorites:mine [nvidia]
```

We get, more or less, what you are looking for, you can swap `mine` for any users ID number (check profiles) to search in their favourites too.